# Can anyone explain why this JavaScript time function interprets a specific day as 25 hours?

Tags: javascript

I was looking into a problem in a web app where the displayed number of days between two dates was one day out in certain circumstances.

I then narrowed this down to being caused by one particular day, namely the 28th of November 2018. If any date pair passed through this day, the number of days is no longer an integer.

Further refining my search I found the reason was that the function was reporting a time of 25 hours for the period from the 28th to the 29th of November, 2018.

```
var fromDate = new Date(2018,09,28).getTime()
var toDate = new Date(2018,09,29).getTime()
var hours = (toDate - fromDate) / (1000 * 3600)
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: End of daylight savings

Comment: If your timezone uses [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) then there is one day each year (in the autumn) that has exactly 25 hours (when the DST ends) and another one in the spring that has only 23 hours (when the DST starts).

Comment: If you console.log the date, you'll see that it's gone from `GMT+0200` to `GMT+0100`

Comment: BTW, it's 28th October not November.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/maxofpower/538efwj9/1/ it alert 24

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, completely forgot about day light savings having an affect on this, thought it would be in utc!

Comment: @Mohammad it'll depend on your local timezone and when/if daylight savings is applied.

Comment: @puzi oh you are right.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, in, for example, Europe, Daylight Savings Time ends on the 28th of October, 2 AM becomes 1 AM if I'm not mistaken, resulting in a day that takes 25 hours.

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2017.html